# modifying two dimensional array ruby

Tags: ruby

if I create this Array:

```
a = Array.new(3,Array.new(2,0))
```

it creates:

```
=> [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

And when I try to change specific element:

```
a[0][0] = 3
```

it changes multiple values:

```
 => [[3, 0], [3, 0], [3, 0]]
```

Why is this happening? And how can I change a specific element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to change how you're initializing your Array ([this is a known issue](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas)) to this:

```
a = Array.new(3) { Array.new(2,0) }
```

The difference between your version and this version is that the `Array.new(2,0)` only occurs once. You're creating one array with 3 "pointers" to the second array. You can see this demonstrated in the following code:

```
a = Array.new(3,Array.new(2,0))
a.map { |a| a.object_id }
#=> [70246027840960, 70246027840960, 70246027840960] # Same object ids!

a = Array.new(3) { Array.new(2,0) }
a.map { |a| a.object_id }
#=> [70246028007600, 70246028007580, 70246028007560] # Different object ids
```

Comment: This is fine if the default value is immutable, as are Fixnum's. If `a = Array.new(3) { Array.new(2,'a') }`, (`a` being mutable) and you reassign an element, `a[0][0] = 'b'`, not a problem: `a #=> [["b","a"], ["a","a"], ["a","a"]]`. If, however, you *replace* an element, `a[0][0].replace('b')`, you get `[["b","b"], ["a","a"], ["a", "a"]]`. (Be sure to first reinitialize `a` if you wish to test this.) If you use `a = Array.new(3) { Array.new(2) {'a'} }`, then `a[0][0].replace('b'); a #=> [["b","a"], ["a","a"], ["a","a"]]`, as desired. If you're unsure, put the default in a block.

Answer (score 4):

You might need to refer to [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas)

`Array.new(3,Array.new(2,0))` can be understood in 2 steps -

1. a new array `Array.new(2,0)` is created
2. again a new array is created with 3 elements with the same object (1) in all 3 places.

Hence, changing a value in any of the subarrays changes values in each one of them. The sub arrays are referring to the same object.

As Gavin Miller pointed out, you will need to use `a = Array.new(3) { Array.new(2,0) }` to change each element.